# How to add premium command in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to add a premium command to my discord bot. So, how could I do so using JSON or any other database? My aim is that it will check whether a user id is in database or not if yes then give the desired output else give an error.

Note: Premium means a user which has taken some kind of subscription or paid for bot services.

```
@bot.command()
# Do some kind of test here 
async def premiumtest(ctx):
  await ctx.send("hi , premuim user")
```

Comment: What do you mean by Premium? Is the user a Booster? A member of your Patreon? The code you provided does not show what you have tried, and you have not detailed what you actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are trying to make a "premium/supporter" command system.

This is very easy (unless you want to set up the whole website and subscriptions EG: mee6)

A good way of limiting the command(s) to a set of users is using a database and a check function.

The first thing you want to do is make a file in the same folder as the main bot file.

Let's call this "premium_users.json". Inside of this file put "[]" so python can open and read this as a list.

Then at the top of your python file, place this code `import json'

Once this is done we can work on adding premium users to the list.

Create a new command called `addpremium` (or whatever you choose).

The code for this command is:

```
@bot.command()
async def addpremium(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.id != 578485884699: #put your user id on discord here
        return

    with open("premium_users.json") as f:
        premium_users_list = json.load(f)

    if user.id not in premium_users_list:
        premium_users_list.append(user.id)

    with open("premium_users.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(premium_users_list, f)

    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has been added!")
```

This command will add a mentioned user to the list!

It will ignore anyone that isn't you!

Now we do the same, but it's the remove command.

```
@bot.command()
async def removepremium(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.id != 578485884699: #put your user id on discord here
        return

    with open("premium_users.json") as f:
        premium_users_list = json.load(f)

    if user.id in premium_users_list:
        premium_users_list.remove(user.id)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} is not in the list, so they cannot be removed!")
        return

    with open("premium_users.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(premium_users_list, f)

    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has been removed!")
```

Now that we have a way to add and remove users we can work on letting these users use commands!

When you only want to let a premium user use a command do this.

First, import `check` from `discord.ext.commands`

```
from discord.ext.commands import check
```

Now that we have that done, we need to make a check function that checks if the user running the command is in the premium list.

```
def check_if_user_has_premium(ctx):
    with open("premium_users.json") as f:
        premium_users_list = json.load(f)
        if ctx.author.id not in premium_users_list:
            return False

    return True
```

Then to apply this check to your premium commands, simply add this code to the command.

```
@check(check_if_user_has_premium)
```

So the command would look something like this:

```
@bot.command()
@check(check_if_user_has_premium)
async def apremiumcommand(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello premium user!")
```

Then if you really want to you can make it do the bot responds with a error message if the user doesn't have premium:

```
@apremiumcommand.error
async def apremiumcommand_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send("Sorry, but you are not a premium user!")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: thankyou but with this i have to add manually

Comment: yea, how else do you want to do it?